# Rails 5 - Active Storage - Variant - Exception: "#<MiniMagick::Error: `mogrify -resize-to-fit [800, 800]"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Rails 5.2.0 (as API)

*/config/application.rb*

> config.active_storage.variant_processor = :vips

Problem:

*/serializers/api/v1/user/current_user_serializer.rb*

```
class Api::V1::User::CurrentUserSerializer < Api::V1::User::BaseSerializer
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  attributes(
    [...]
    :avatar
    :created_at
  )

  def avatar
    if object.avatar.attachment
      avatar = {
        image: url_for( object.avatar ), # This one works
        thumb: url_for( object.avatar.variant(resize_to_fit: [800, 800]) ), # EXCEPTION
        thumb_test: url_for( object.avatar.variant(resize: '800x800') ) # Returns image of size: 640x800 (expected 800x800)
      }
    end
  end
end
```

I get the following exception:

```
exception: "<MiniMagick::Error: `mogrify -resize-to-fit [800, 800] /tmp/mini_magick20180625-19749-rghjbg.jpg` failed with error: mogrify.im6: unrecognized option `-resize-to-fit' @ error/mogrify.c/MogrifyImageCommand/5519. >"
```

---

**EDIT**

Thanks @George Claghorn

I now created my own variant based on this post:
https://prograils.com/posts/rails-5-2-active-storage-new-approach-to-file-uploads

*lib/active_storage_variants.rb*

```
class ActiveStorageVariants
  class << self
    def resize_to_fill(width:, height:, blob:, gravity: 'Center')
      blob.analyze unless blob.analyzed?

      cols = blob.metadata[:width].to_f
      rows = blob.metadata[:height].to_f
      if width != cols || height != rows
        scale_x = width / cols
        scale_y = height / rows
        if scale_x >= scale_y
          cols = (scale_x * (cols + 0.5)).round
          resize = cols.to_s
        else
          rows = (scale_y * (rows + 0.5)).round
          resize = "x#{rows}"
        end
      end

      {
        resize: resize,
        gravity: gravity,
        background: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.0)',
        extent: cols != width || rows != height ? "#{width}x#{height}" : ''
      }.merge(optimize_hash(blob))
    end
  end
end
```

*/models/concerns/users/active_storage_variants.rb*

```
require 'active_storage_variants' # /lib/active_storage_variants.rb

module Users::ActiveStorageVariants

  def avatar_thumbnail
    variation = ActiveStorage::Variation.new(
      ActiveStorageVariants.resize_to_fill(
        width: 300, height: 300, blob: avatar.blob
      )
    )
    ActiveStorage::Variant.new(avatar.blob, variation)
  end
end
```

*/models/user.rb*

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...

  ## Concerns
  include Users::ActiveStorageVariants

  ...
end
```

To call it:

> user.avatar_thumbnail

Comment: I think its usually format of `"800x800"` rather than `[800,800]` https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`resize_to_fit: [800, 800]` is an [ImageProcessing](https://github.com/janko-m/image_processing) transformation. Rails 5.2 doesn’t use ImageProcessing and thus doesn’t support libvips; it uses MiniMagick directly instead.

Rails 6 will switch to ImageProcessing and add libvips support. To use libvips now, prior to the release of Rails 6, bundle the master branch of the rails/rails repository on GitHub:

```
# Gemfile
gem "rails", github: "rails/rails"
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution [here](https://mindaslab.github.io/2018/06/23/a-possible-mistake-in-rails-active-storage-documentation.html)

Replacing this,

```
<%= image_tag user.avatar.variant(resize_to_fit: [100, 100]) %>
```

with,

```
<%= image_tag user.avatar.variant(resize: "100 x100") %>
```

Worked for me. Even though the office document does the former way.

Comment: Actually I was missing image_processing gem. When I added it the problem was resolved.